# Creating conan test_package recipe

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm currently playing around with conan. So I've created two small project:
The first project is a small library "fcdk": https://github.com/lmarzull/fcdk/tree/devel

The second is a project holding the conan and circle-ci stuff (don't know yet if I should group the library/conan/circle-ci in a single project, but this is not yet the point).
The second project is called "fcdk-conan"

I decide to put the unit test of the library inside the fcdk-conan project in the "test_package" directory. I do so to avoid a dependencies on google test in my "fcdk" library and to rather have this dependency in the fcdk-conan project (don't know if it's a good idea)

I've create a very litte test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

And all is fine.

But now, I want to add some Unit test of my library. So I need to find/compile/link the "fcdk" library. So I change the main.cc file to this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcdk/CommandLineOptionFlag.h>

int
main()
{
  FCDK::CommandLineOptionFlag show_help('h', "help", "show this help message");
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Here the CMakeLists.txt of the test_package directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(FcdkTest CXX)


include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)


add_executable(
  test-fcdk
  main.cc
)
target_include_directories(test-fcdk PUBLIC ${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_FCDK})
target_link_libraries(test-fcdk PUBLIC ${CONAN_LIBS_FCDK})
target_link_libraries(test-fcdk PUBLIC CONAN_PKG::fcdk)

enable_testing()
add_test(NAME test-fcdk
         WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
         COMMAND test-fcdk)
```

And the conan recipe:

```
import os
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools


class FcdkTestConan(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "cmake"
    requires = "fcdk/1.0.0"

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def test(self):
        if not tools.cross_building(self.settings):
            os.chdir("bin")
            self.run(".%stest-fcdk" % os.sep)
```

I could not achieve the test_package to link correctly.

```
CMakeFiles/test-fcdk.dir/main.cc.o: In function `FCDK::CommandLineOptionFlag::accept(FCDK::VisitorBase&)':
main.cc:(.text._ZN4FCDK21CommandLineOptionFlag6acceptERNS_11VisitorBaseE[_ZN4FCDK21CommandLineOptionFlag6acceptERNS_11VisitorBaseE]+0xa1): undefined reference to `FCDK::demangleTypename(char const*)'
main.cc:(.text._ZN4FCDK21CommandLineOptionFlag6acceptERNS_11VisitorBaseE[_ZN4FCDK21CommandLineOptionFlag6acceptERNS_11VisitorBaseE]+0xdd): undefined reference to `FCDK::demangleTypename(char const*)'
CMakeFiles/test-fcdk.dir/main.cc.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text.startup+0x5e): undefined reference to `FCDK::CommandLineOptionFlag::CommandLineOptionFlag(char, std::string, std::string)'
```

All the previous step:

```
conan source 
conan install
conan build
conan package
conan export-pkg
```

was fine and seems correct to me. I put here the content of the conan package command:

```
package/
package/conaninfo.txt
package/include
package/include/fcdk
package/include/fcdk/Exception.h
package/include/fcdk/CommandLineOption.h
package/include/fcdk/CommandLineOptionWithValue.h
package/include/fcdk/Visitor.h
package/include/fcdk/ABI.h
package/include/fcdk/CommandLineParser.h
package/include/fcdk/CommandLineOptionFlag.h
package/conanmanifest.txt
package/lib
package/lib/libfcdk.a
package/share
package/share/cmake
package/share/cmake/fcdk
package/share/cmake/fcdk/fcdkTargets.cmake
package/share/cmake/fcdk/fcdkTargets-release.cmake
```

I've also look at the missing symbol in the libfcdk.a
For example:

```
                 U FCDK::demangleTypename[abi:cxx11](char const*)
                 U FCDK::demangleTypename[abi:cxx11](char const*)
0000000000000000 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN4FCDK16demangleTypenameB5cxx11EPKc
0000000000000000 T FCDK::demangleTypename[abi:cxx11](char const*)
```

When I run the make with VERBOSE=1, I do not see the fcdk library information on the link command

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test-fcdk.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -m64 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/test-fcdk.dir/main.cc.o  -o bin/test-fcdk 
CMakeFiles/test-fcdk.dir/main.cc.o: In function `FCDK::CommandLineOptionFlag::accept(FCDK::VisitorBase&)':
```

Could someone help me to figure out whay the test_pacakge recipe does not link agains my fcdk/1.0.0 package please ?

Thank you very much

EDIT: Conan repository with test_pacakge updated
https://github.com/lmarzull/fcdk-conan/tree/devel

Comment: It would seem that the `conan_basic_setup()` call is not populating your `CONAN_PKG::fcdk` CMake target.

Comment: could you, please, post your sources with test package to github? Your repos are not containing test package you mentioned here

Comment: @ymochurad: I've edited my question with the link to the 'fcdk-conan' repository on github. Thank you

Comment: I think that you need to declare the library you are linking to in your main conanfile using `self.cpp_info.libdirs` and `self.cpp_info.libs`. More details here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#method-package-info

Comment: @ymochurad: Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, many thanks to @ymochurad

He points me to filling the self.cpp_info.libs with the name of the given library.

But one this was done, the story continue. I need to modify

test_package/CMakeLists.txt
test_package/conanfile.py

```
# conanfile.py
def package_info(self):
  self.cpp_info.libs = [ "fcdk" ]
```

And

```
# test_package/CMakeLists.txt
FIND_PACKAGE(fcdk REQUIRED)

# remove conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)
# and replace with:
conan_basic_setup()

# Add ${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
target_include_directories(test-fcdk
  PRIVATE ${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# and also fcdk_LIBRARIES in link directive
target_link_libraries(test-fcdk ${fcdk_LIBRARIES})
```

And

```
# test_package/conanfile.py
def config_options(self):
  self.settings.compiler.libcxx = "libstdc++11"
```

All of those modifications resolve the initial problem.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the `test_package` folder is that, if it contains a `conanfile.py` with a `test()` function, Conan will automatically handle it once the package is fully created.

---

Starting from the following basic project structure, let's build a simple library with a single dependency:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── conanfile.py
├── src
│   ├── mylib.cpp
│   └── mylib.hpp
└── test_package
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── conanfile.py
    └── main.cpp
```

Top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(mylib)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED) // Version is handled by Conan

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/mylib.cpp src/mylib.hpp)
target_link_library(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE fmt::fmt)

// This will automatically install at the right place depending on the platform
// e.g. a .DLL file goes to bin while .SO/.A/.LIB files go to lib
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME})
install(DIRECTORY src/
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp")
```

Top-level `conanfile.py`:

```py
from conan             import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, cmake_layout


class MylibConan(ConanFile):
    name            = "mylib"
    version         = "1.0.0"
    settings        = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires        = "fmt/9.1.0"
    options         = {"shared": [True, False], "fPIC": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False, "fPIC": True}
    generators      = "CMakeToolchain", "CMakeDeps"
    exports_sources = "CMakeLists.txt", "src/*"

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        CMake(self).install()

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = [self.name]
```

`test_package/main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <mylib/mylib.hpp>

int main()
{
    mylib();
}
```

`test_package/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(test_package)

find_package(mylib QUIET)
if(NOT mylib_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "This project can only be built with a 'conan create' command in the parent directory!")
endif()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
// Put the exe in the same place for both Single- and Multi-Config generators
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY bin/$<0:>)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mylib::mylib)
```

`test_package/conanfile.py`:

```py
from conan             import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, cmake_layout
from os.path           import join


class MylibTestConan(ConanFile):
    settings   = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "CMakeToolchain", "CMakeDeps"

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires(self.tested_reference_str)

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def test(self):
        self.run(join(self.build_folder, "bin", "test_package"))
```

---

Now you can call `conan create .` and your `test_package` will automatically get built and run in your local directory.